# Realm Studio for windows javascript error

Tags: android, realm, windows-7-x64

I am trying to install `Realm` `Studio` on my `windows` 7 machine (x64).

After install is complete and any time I'm trying to open `Realm` `Studio` I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realm Studio only works on Windows 8.1 and above.

---

This is the reply I got from Realm:

> I've had a conversation with our developers on Realm JS (that Studio is dependent on) and it turns out that we target Windows 8.1 and up.
>
> Sorry about that - we should probably update our documentation to make this perfectly clear.

---

Personally, I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 (choose amd64) on a virtual machine to use Realm Studio on Win7.

Comment: But why?! What is `Realm JS`?

Comment: `Realm-Javascript` of course. But it's okay, as I said, you can use VirtualBox to run an Ubuntu 16.04, where Realm Studio works perfectly fine.